# Boost Circular Buffer pointer access (c++)

Tags: boost, iterator, buffer, circular-buffer

I would like to use the Boost circular buffer to store arrays that are produced by a hardware API.  The API takes in the address of the memory location and pushes the array accordingly.  So I have the following:

```
typedef unsigned char API_data [10];

boost::circular_buffer<API_data> data(10);
boost::circular_buffer<API_data>::iterator it = data.begin();
```

But I cannot pass the pointer `it` to the API because:

> no suitable conversion function from "`boost::cb_details::iterator<boost::circular_buffer<API_data, std::allocator<API_data>>, boost::cb_details::nonconst_traits<boost::container::allocator_traits<std::allocator<API_data>>>>`" to `LPVOID` exists.

The API is expecting a pointer of type `LPVOID` but `it` pointer is of different type.

Comment: `it` is not any sort of a pointer.

Comment: You probably can get the start of the buffer with `&*it` however while that most likely will compile I do not expect it to work because a circular buffer is not only a buffer, it also has a start and end index. And these indexes that boost maintains for you have to also be updated correctly by the hardware to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thank you guys for your inputs!  I assumed that `it` is a pointer because the example in the boost circular buffer documentation dereferences `it` to obtain the value stored at the location.  I am not sufficiently experienced to find the boost circular buffer documentation anything other than confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Circular buffer API is similar to `::std::vector` API. But there is a catch. First, items stored in circular buffer must be copy assignable so you can not store raw arrays in it. Second, you supply container capacity in constructor, not initial container size so before trying to pass a pointer to stored item you need to make sure that it is there. Pushing into circular buffer may drop oldest items if buffer is full unlike `std::vector` which will always grow. Then you can get a reference to a pushed item and convert it to pointer to void.

```
using API_data_buffer = ::std::array< unsigned char, 10 >;

::boost::circular_buffer< API_data_buffer > buffers(10); // buffers is still empty!
buffers.push_back();
auto & api_data_buffer{buffers.back()};
auto const p_void_api_data{reinterpret_cast< void * >(reinterpret_cast< ::std::uintptr_t >(api_data_buffer.data()))};
```

Comment: Thank you @VTT for this information.  I was uncertain whether or not I could store raw arrays in the circular buffer and was also considering using `std::vector`.  So I'll proceed accordingly.  Thanks again!